# Is RWD a good idea on a 2.5 tonne car?

Tags: drivetrain, weight

Hypothetically speaking, if you were to produce a 2.5 tonne car what drive train configuration would suit it best? My initial thought would be a 4x4 set up as this is most common in heavier vehicles.

Furthermore if we say the vehicle in question is electrically driven, with one motor at the rear. The vehicle is capable of high torque and power.

Would this be a good idea, or is it a recipe for disaster and how would the car behave on the road?

Comment: This sounds like it would be a fascinating topic for a discussion forum but I don't see how it isn't way too broad for a Q&A site. "Better" is subjective and will depend on a lot of other factors.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  This question may be closed as Primarily Opinion Based soon.  This is a Question/Answer site, so we need questions that can have a single correct answer.  Asking for things like "best," or "good idea" can often have answers that are subjective, based on what the specific person answering thinks.  Try to edit your question to clarify a single, objective question that we could help answer!

Comment: @Cullub iven the amount of comments you have just posted, you could have put in less effort by improving the question....

Comment: @SolarMike They were mostly canned, and I'm not experienced in this realm, so I'd be afraid to muck things up

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think 4x4 is most common? may be more prevalent now, but go back prior to the introduction of the Mini and just about every car was rear wheel drive.

If you look at the large cars, then it is only fairly recently that they have started doing 4x4 versions and some of the quality manufacturers have only recently produced a 4x4 variant, think of Rolls Royce... In terms of the number of years they have been producing cars then 4x4 is very new...

In terms of handling, rear wheel drive is not a problem, why do you think F1 cars are rear wheel drive? The use of fwd is to maximize the available space for the occupants...

Comment: FWD was mainly introduced as a fuel saving measure ... it's easier to pull something than it is to push it. FWD cars came into their own during the oil embargoes of the 1970's ... at least that's when FWD cars started showing up en mass here in the States.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 see http://www.design-technology.info/designers/page32.htm also think about the flat floor pan but yes fuel was a consideration and is now even more important...

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 "it's easier to pull something than it is to push it." - that sounds like it came from the marketing department, not from the engineers. Unless you have a credible reference for it, of course.

Comment: @alephzero calculate the forces and reactions when pushing a wheelbarrow and pulling one...

Comment: @SolarMike I've voted to close the question as opinion based, just based on the wording of the question.  If you think you could edit it to be more objective, that'd be great!

Comment: I think the fuel saving comes from decreased friction, because the engine is in the front, and there's a lot of friction in transferring the energy to the back wheels of the car. You need to change the direction of rotation at least once if not twice for RWD cars, whereas FWD needs no such tricks. If the engine was at the back, then RWD would probably be as fuel efficient as FWD.

Answer (score 0):

The "electrically driven" is an important point in this determination. AWD in electric vehicles is generally done with one motor on each axle, and the big disadvantage of RWD/AWD in ICE-powered vehicles - the presence of the transmission tunnel housing the gearbox between the front footwells, and the propshaft running the length of the floorpan, then goes away. This was the main reason that FWD became popular, the engine and transmission was a combined unit attached to the front end of the passenger cell, which was then a box without the intrusions for the drivetrain that then restricted the layout, so smaller cars could have good space inside.

For any car, the  majority of braking effort is done on the front wheels, so for an EV this would indicate that for good regenerative braking, a motor would be needed at the front, otherwise the mechanical front brakes would be dissipating most of the energy and the rear motor would not generate much. For a high performance car, a rear motor makes sense to get good traction on acceleration, making the AWD setup a logical choice, but a heavy, but not high performance car could well get away with a front motor only.

Comment: I've voted to close the question as opinion based, just based on the wording of the question.  If you think you could edit the OP to be more objective, that'd be great!